# Bosun usage of text* in query function

Tags: bosun

I want filter my hosts in a query. To do that according to the docs I can use text* like :

```
q("sum:app.call{host=vpcolt*}", "1m", ""))
```

But in my case, scollector send metrics directly in OpenTSDB. So Bosun doesn't seem to have informations about hosts because * does not incur any additional OpenTSDB API requests.

If I have not wrong, how can I handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are/can use OpenTSDB 2.2, enable it in Bosun's config:

```
tsdbVersion = 2.2
```

then you can use the new [filter syntax](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/config/filters.html):

```
q("sum:app.call{host=iwildcard(vpcolt*)}", "1m", ""))
```

it should work this way, even if Bosun doesn't receive data.